# Reading cell value with applied Text formatting with OpenXML

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to read Excel Sheet, that contains cells with Text formatting.

Some one of columns has values `1`, `1.1`, `1.2` and etc.

In Excel all of these values look good, in cells with Text formatting - `1`, `1.1`, `1.2`.

But when I read that cells with OpenXML, I got values `1`, `1.1000000000000001`, `1.2` - some one of them has decimal parts.

OKay, I checked xl\worksheets\sheet1.xml in *.xlsx file and I see, that really contains value `1.1000000000000001`

```
<row r="3" spans="1:20" ht="15" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
            <c r="A3" s="2">
                <v>1.1000000000000001</v>
            </c>
```

My code is:

```
 List<List<string>> rows = new List<List<string>>();

            List<string> cols;

            spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(excelFilePath, false);

            WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
            SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();

            SharedStringTablePart sstpart = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
            SharedStringTable sst = sstpart.SharedStringTable;

            foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
            {
                cols = new List<string>();
                foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
                {
                    if (c.DataType != null && c.DataType == CellValues.SharedString)
                    {
                        int ssid = int.Parse(c.CellValue.Text);
                        string str = sst.ChildElements[ssid].InnerText;
                        cols.Add(str);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cols.Add(c.CellValue?.InnerText);
                    }
                }
                rows.Add(cols);
            }

            spreadsheetDocument.Close();
```

How shall I get correct value from such cells? For example, `1.1`, but not `1.1000000000000001`.

Comment: Instead of trying to read the raw XML why not use a library like EPPlus, ClosedXML, NPOI ? All of this code can be reduced to `workSheet.Cells[1,1].Text`.

Comment: The main goal - to use library, that support Microsoft, not third-party library.

Comment: In that case you can't use .NET at all. All versions, both .NET Framework and .NET Core depend on NuGet packages and even third-party libraries like JSON.NET. You can't do anything without using a "third party" library

Comment: In fact, Microsoft itself **strongly** advises using third-party open source libraries instead of deprecated classes [like SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0#remarks)

Answer (score 1):

First create this method to get the value of a cell.

```
public static string GetCellValue(WorkbookPart workbookPart, Cell cell)
{
    string value = null;
    if (cell.InnerText.Length > 0)
    {
        value = cell.InnerText;

        // If the cell represents an integer number, you are done. 
        // For dates, this code returns the serialized value that 
        // represents the date. The code handles strings and 
        // Booleans individually. For shared strings, the code 
        // looks up the corresponding value in the shared string 
        // table. For Booleans, the code converts the value into 
        // the words TRUE or FALSE.
        if (cell.DataType != null)
        {
            switch (cell.DataType.Value)
            {
                case CellValues.SharedString:

                    // For shared strings, look up the value in the
                    // shared strings table.
                    var stringTable =
                        workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>()
                        .FirstOrDefault();

                    // If the shared string table is missing, something 
                    // is wrong. Return the index that is in
                    // the cell. Otherwise, look up the correct text in 
                    // the table.
                    if (stringTable != null)
                    {
                        value =
                            stringTable.SharedStringTable
                            .ElementAt(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
                    }
                    break;

                case CellValues.Boolean:
                    value = value switch
                    {
                        "0" => "FALSE",
                        _ => "TRUE",
                    };
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Then use this code for your inner for loop:

```
foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
{
    string str = GetCellValue(workbookPart, c);
    cols.add(str);
}
```

The `GetCellValue` method is inspired by Microsoft documentation on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-retrieve-the-values-of-cells-in-a-spreadsheet)